# Object variables are not changing in the innerscope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a function called Product which I use to create objects in JavaScript. Now I have a function called setProduct which gets data from my database (websql) and sets all these data from the database in the current object. This is my code:

```
function Product(nr, name, description, brand, category, price, tags, color, seccolor, image, sizes, db) {
    this.nr             = nr;
    this.name           = name;
    this.description    = description;
    this.brand          = brand;
    this.category       = category;
    this.price          = price;
    this.tags           = tags;
    this.color          = color;
    this.seccolor       = color;
    this.image          = image;
    this.sizes          = sizes;
    this.db             = db;

        Product.prototype.setProduct = function(id, cb) {
        var self = this;
        var query = "SELECT * from products WHERE id='"+id+"';"
        var res;
        this.db.exec(query, function(results) {
            res = results.rows.item(0);
            self.nr             = res.prod_nr;
            self.description    = res.prod_description;
            self.brand          = res.prod_brand;
            self.category       = res.prod_category;
            self.price          = res.prod_price;
            self.tags           = res.prod_tags;
            self.color          = res.prod_color;
            self.seccolor       = res.prod_sec_color;
            self.image          = res.prod_image;
            self.sizes          = res.available_sizes;
            self.name           = res.prod_name;
            cb(true);
        });
    };
}
```

this.db = my database object. setProduct calls the exec function from that object. That's this code:

```
Database.prototype.exec = function(query, cb) {
        this.db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, results) {



                if (typeof(cb) == 'function') {

                        cb(results);
                    }
                });
            });
   }
```

I've tried to use several console.logs to see where the data gets lost, but I can't find it somehow.

And here is where it goes wrong:

```
$("div#home").off('click').on('click','li', function() { 
            var product = prod;
            var prod_id = $(this).attr("id");
            prod.setProduct(prod_id, function(a) {
                if (a) {
                    console.log(prod.name); // console.log gives undefined
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Use debugger instead of `console.log()`. PS: it's **very** strange to define prototype functions in the constructor

Comment: @zerkms what debugger do you mean? Okay thanks for the tip. I'll put the prototype functions outside of the constructor :)

Comment: for example - google chrome developer tools js debugger PS: here is an article about when `console.log` may lie to you: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

Comment: I can't see any problem with your object scope. Are you initializing a product with the _new_ keyword? e.g: `test = new Product();` - if so, the next step is to confirm that the `this.db.exec` callback has the correct data.

Comment: @MattStone yes I do initialize a new product object. Sorry for not including that in my post. this.db.exec has the correct data because it works for all my other functions, and I console.log'd that

Comment: @zerkms That's interesting! Thanks for the information. Will use it right now.

Comment: @AngeloA I've simulated the response from your DB in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knN4m/2/). As you can see, the output is as you would expect. Can you please double check that the callback from `this.db.exec()` has the data you expect it to?

Comment: the .db works. I've forgot to add some essential code, sorry. Check my edit. There it's going wrong actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution! 
I've added the current object into a new variable to use in innerscope but I forgot to use it

```
$("div#home").off('click').on('click','li', function() { 
            var product = prod; // FOR THE INNER SCOPE
            var prod_id = $(this).attr("id");
            prod.setProduct(prod_id, function(a) {
                if (a) {
                    console.log(prod.name); // prod.name has to be product.name, as defined above
                    console.log(product.name); // WORKS!

                }
            });
        });
}
```